# Help with manipulating a change of variable in Integration

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Knowing:

$$\phi (x)=\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \frac { dt }{ \sqrt { 1-{ x }^{ 2 } \sin ^{ 2 }(t) }  }  } $$

I am trying to demonstrate that: $\phi (x)=\frac { 1 }{ 1+x } \phi \left( \frac { 2\sqrt { x }  }{ 1+x }  \right) $

Having: $\varphi (t)=arcsin\left( \frac { \left( 1+x \right) \cdot sin(t) }{ 1+x\cdot { sin }^{ 2 }(t) }  \right) $

I already know that the function $\varphi$ is differentiable once, as well as its inverse bijection ${ \varphi  }^{ -1 }$, and ${ \varphi  }^{ ' }(t)=\frac { (1+x)\cdot \left( 1-x\cdot { sin }^{ 2 }(t) \right)  }{ \left( 1+x\cdot { sin }^{ 2 }(t) \right) \sqrt { 1-{ x }^{ 2 }\cdot { sin }^{ 2 }(t) }  } $

I tried to use a change of variable in $\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \frac { dt }{ \sqrt { 1-{ x }^{ 2 }\cdot { sin }^{ 2 }(t) }  }  } $ with $t=u(t)$ but I always get stuck. If someone could help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know that your integral is an elliptic integral, found here: http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to learn more about it.